# What is an endpoint in the context of TLS?

Tags: tls, authentication, oauth2, mutual

What is the purpose of endpoints in mutual TLS authentication? Actually, what do we mean by an endpoint? I am following this [OAuth 2.0 Mutual-TLS Client Authentication and Certificate-Bound Access Tokens](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8705/?include_text=1)

If a Client A wants to gain access on a protected resource hosted by some other Entity B, then wants an access token from the authorization server. Most specifically it "talks" to the token endpoint of the authorization server.

But also the entity that gives the protected resource to the client cannot considered as an endpoint?

i am confused here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint of a network communication is the computer, program, or function which initiates or ultimately receives the communication. Since TLS is "designed to establish a secure connection between a client and a server communicating over an insecure channel" (RFC 5246), it's probably safe to assume the paper you linked to is talking about client & server endpoints.

So, without endpoints, TLS itself would have no purpose. I think that's the best your question can be answered.

Comment: i edit my question above to make more sense

Comment: Yes, client + authorization server and client + resource owner are both valid endpoint pairs. Is there a particular passage in the paper where the term needs further clarification?

Comment: Is your question something like, "Why should the client perform mutual TLS with just the authorization server when it can do it with the resource server instead/also?"

Comment: thank you for the answer. My confusion is the following. We have an endpoint which is the part that holds the protected resource. Also, auth server has a token endpoint. But I am reading from here https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/get-started/subscriptions-cloud/ocuid/oauth-endpoints.html that " An endpoint is typically a URI on a web server, but OAuth endpoints are the URLs that you use to make OAuth authentication requests. So the token endpoint in auth server is a URL? Also, the authorization endpoint is located in auth server on the protected resource?

Comment: also, I would like to here the answer in the above statement  "Why should the client perform mutual TLS with just the authorization server when it can do it with the resource server instead/also? because is something that I am interested to know

Comment: if you ask me the answer auth server is necessary for issue tokens so after the client can access the protected resource. Also, the resource server must reach the auth server in order to check the hash of the certificate that is embedded inside the access token